# How to use Greater than and less. Like a range from 5-10

Tags: ios, objective-c

My application uses animation to push items over the screen. If there are more than 3 items it changes the animation, and adding ten more it changes it even more.

I've created iF and else if statements for my app. The first is: `if items = 0`. Then no animations

Second is `else if items < 3`. Then I reduce the force

The third is `else items = 0`. Then there is no animation

What I want to do is create an if statement for a range of numbers: i.e..
`else if items >= 7, but <= 3`. Then if there were anywhere from 3-7 items the force would be:...

Here is my code I'm working on as an example:

```
else if
        ([self.reorderedButtons count] <= 4) {
        pushBehavior.pushDirection      = CGVectorMake(0, self.force * .5);
        [self.animator addBehavior:pushBehavior];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule:
Any if-clause will unfold top to bottom. That is

```
if (i < 3) {
    // Code for i < 3
} else if (i <= 7) {
    // Code for 3 <= i <= 7
} else {
    // Code for i > 7
}
```

This applies to all major languages.

Comment: I reversed the order and got it working through your method as well. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason an AND statement won't work?

You can always combine conditionals with the && (AND) operator or the || (Or operator)

```
 if([self.reorderedButtons count] <= 7 && [self.reorderedButtons count] >= 3)
    //Do Function
```

Comment: no thats perfect. I had tried that but the wrong way. Seeing the syntax makes sense now. I had been trying ([self.reorderedButtons count] <= 7 && >+ 3)

Comment: @user3786510 Notice that you don't have to include conditions already checked in previous if-clauses of one if-else if...-else chain. See my answer for details on that. In your particular case I suspect that `[self.reorderedButtons count] < 3` has been tested to false already, so `>=3` is guaranteed to be true.

Comment: @AlexR has a great point about the cascading effect of if statements.  If it is caught by a previous condition, it won't fall through to the next.